# Running Windows 7 inside VirtualBox on OSX Mountain Lion breaks internet connection

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, virtualbox

I am facing the issue when I boot Guest Windows 7 inside VirtualBox and in a couple of minutes internet connection on host becomes very unstable, losing pings, then just remote addresses stop responding completely. Once I stop VirtualBox instance, everything turns back fine again.

I clearly see this issue as connected to VirtualBox, because I can turn on/off VirtualBox multiple times at once and it happens all the way I described.

I tried NAT, Host-only, Bridged, switched all firewalls off. What I found is guest OS can't ping my WiFi router that is 192.168.1.1, but pings the host OS that is 192.168.1.123.

How can I detect a clue why it can happen?

Comment: What version of VirtualBox?

Comment: 4.2.18. Seems to be the latest as Update manager doesn't find newer versions.

Comment: What IP address/mask/gateway are being assigned to the Win7 guest?